# All elements in Form is cleared before FormClosing Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to check a label value on the form closing event:

```
  private void FrmDialog_FormClosing(object sender,
 System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
           if(label.Text == "something")
                {
                  doSomething();
                }
        }
```

However, it seems like all the elements in the form is cleared before the FormClosing event, as label is null. Is there any way to do what I am describing?

Comment: `label.text` wouldn't compile... Are you sure you are looking at the right label ? Nothing will touch your form component data on closing, unless there is explicate code to do such

Comment: oops ***explicit***

Comment: try to get the label.text first then. try adding a `string` and use this in `if`. cause like @TheGeneral comment said those value will not just disappear unless code told it to.

Comment: Ye, it was just a typo, not related to the issue. I fixed it in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the typing error in `label.Text`, you can be certain that during the event handling of event Form.Closing, every control that you didn't dispose yourself is still fully functional. Even during Form.Closed and during `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` the controls should still be there, otherwise, they couldn't be disposed, could they.

If your debugger says otherwise, check whether you really subscribed to event Form.Closing.
Put a breakpoint in procedure `Dispose(bool disposing)`, and check whether your event handler is called before Dispose.

Answer (score -2):

Please, try to use:

```
label.Text
```

Comment: I am 99.934534% sure this will not be the right answer